# kendo ui transport data is null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vb.net, kendo-ui

Can anyone explain to me why the obj parameter in the httpGet values are null/undefined! I'm using vb so there equal to Nothing! I don't understand why I can get the correct values from the data.

```
var newGridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "/api/Stuff/",
            dataType: "json",
            data: 
                function(){

                    return { name: "Bob" };
                }

        }
    }
});
```

My visual basic code is

```
Structure g
    Public name As String
End Structure


<HttpGet>
Function returnGrid(<FromBody()> obj As g) As  HttpResponseMessage

    Return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK)
End Function
```

Comment: It looks like all you are doing is returning HTTP status code 200 - OK. It's been a while since I've done Kendo stuff, but I think you're going to have to return more than an HTTP status code.

Comment: @Lex I'm using the Visual Studio Debugger to step through the function to view the value of obj. The value is set to Nothing and doesn't get the value of name that is being sent over. The returnGrid function is hit, but the parameter values are never assigned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending a function as the data, I think you want the return of the function so you would need to call it by including parens after it:

```
var newGridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "/api/Stuff/",
            dataType: "json",
            data: 
                function(){    
                    return { name: "Bob" };
                }()
        }
    }
});
```

But that seems kind of silly when you could just do:

```
 data: { name: "Bob" }
```

> udpate

You can't get data `FromBody` with a GET request. Remove `<FromBody()>` and the model binder will look in the query string for data and it should work.

Comment: I tried your method and still haven't been able to get it to work. I used a function because that how its shown to be down in the kendo ui documentation page that I found I modified the functiion a bit but still I receive nothing on the server side! My server side function is hit but the values of the parameter are null

Comment: var newGridDS = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/api/Stuff/",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {name:"Bob"}
                },
                parameterMap: function (data, type) {
                    if (type == 'read') {
                        return { models: kendo.stringify(data.models) };
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    model: { name: "name" }
                }
            },
        });

Comment: @James, please see my update and please point me to the kendo example that shows the data as a function.

Comment: This is the link to the documentation. I changed from <FromBody()> to ByVal obj As g but now I'm getting a 404 (Not Found) error and my server function is never hit

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.create.data

Comment: @James, interesting. I almost think it might be a typo in the documentation. See [this dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/EvIYi) . If I do not use parens on the function in `data: function() { return movies; }()` then it does not pull data.

Comment: That definitely has to be a typo and explains half my problems lol

Comment: @James, experiment with your controller. Make the parameter `object` instead of `g`, or take the parameter out completely and see if it is hit. Also inspect the Request and look at the URL to see what is in the querystring.

Comment: Will do! I'll let you know once I solve it what the problem might be! Thanks for the help!!

Comment: I'm still not sure what the problem is, but seems kendo has an issue with sending objects in the query string. I just changed the read URL to include the fields I wanted and I can get the values from there on the server instead of passing in an object 

 transport: {
                read: {
                    type:"POST",
                    url: "/api/Stuff"+"?name=Bob&id=5",
               }
            }